# Stop function from executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using this angular materials dialog service and one of the functions on

``` line 5050 ``calculateZoomToOrigin: function (element, originator) { ```

makes the dialog zoom in and then on close it zooms out. I would like to stop this function from executing, I don't want it to do any zooming.

Comment: you are asking the wrong question here.  The question shouldn't be "how do I stop this function" but "how do I configure this service"
.

Comment: There are no configurable options for zoom:boolean; unfortunately